# My hedgehog won’t eat

Tags: health, hedgehog

So I’ve had my hedgehog for almost a year and he’s just stopped eating. If I hand feed him meal worms he will eat them but not his actual food.

He’s started acting funny. He’s slower that usual and he seemed to wobble when I picked him up this morning. It took him a lot longer to uncurl then usual.

Is there any reason for me to worry?

Comment: Please give us some more information. Does this hedgehog live indoors or outdoors? Are you living on the northern hemisphere (read: is it becomming winter where you live)? What are you feeding the hedgehog besides mealworms? Should its condition worsen drastically, go see a vet immediately instead of asking the internet for help.

Comment: as @Elmy say we need more information,what types of food do you give it,indoor/outdoor,is it dewormed,any vaccsines given,type of enclosure it lives in.how do you manage the need for hibernation,have it ever been seen by a vet.if you think it is ill take it to your vet first and ask questions here later.

Comment: He is indoors and yea it is becoming winter and I did some research I think he was just getting to cold.  I read that Hedgehogs don’t need vaccinations but he does have a vet appointment next week so I am taking him. He lives in a cage kind of like a hamster cage but it is Fairly large so that’s not a problem. I only asked the internet for help because I don’t have a lot of money at the moment. But he seems to be testing better I just had to make his enclosure warmer.

Comment: Please ask the vet about how you can provide the right conditions for him to go into hibernation. Hedgehogs in the wild hibernate during winter and you should try to let him follow this natural cycle.